# Apache Http.conf subdomain

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Http.conf file working fine for main domain, but I'm trying to create a subdomain and it keeps sending them both to the test page. I'm sure the problem is here (httpd.conf) but I'm not 100% on what all of this is doing.

```
ServerName 1.2.3.4 #hidden

<VirtualHost *:3304>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    LogLevel warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
    SSLCertificateFile /cert/mydomain_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /cert/mydomain_com.key
    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    UserDir "html/" 
</VirtualHost>

SSLEngine off
SSLVerifyClient none
KeepAlive on

#the new sub domain - adding this causes the error   
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4>
    ServerName testsite.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias testsite.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www_demo/public_html"
</VirtualHost>
```

Both are running a PHP framework but only the main domain requires SSL protection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try removing the address from the second virtualhost and use a port like the first one.

Comment: Has stopped redirecting to the test page which is great thankyou, but will only show the main website on both I used *:81

Comment: What do you enter into the browser when connecting? Make sure you add the port like 'domain.com:<port>' if you're not using port 80

Comment: Times out, that could be an issue with the application but its working locally

Comment: Try telnet to this port (no local ip) - if not work, You must open port in firewall

Comment: Firewall of course! I locked it down tight during set-up, thanks i bet that's it